# decompose and deconvolve a signal using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, convolution

I have a complex signal. I filtered this signal using a bandpass filter and I ended up to saw teeth wave.

```
data=load(../file, '-mat');
fs=5;
fc=[0.05 1.5];      
[b,a]=butter(3,fc/(fs/2),'bandpass');
data = filter(b,a,data')';
```

Then I change the amplitude of half of the saw tooth to 3 times larger as below:

```
saw_new=[data(1:length(data)/2), 3*data(((length(data)/2)+1):end)];
```

Now the question is how Insert the new sawtooth to the data and make a new data in such a way that if some body use bandpass filter this time it gets  saw_new as a result for using bandpass filter. In summary I want to:

1. use a band pass filter to extract the sawtooth wave ( done).
2. multiply the sawtooth wave to the number 2 so it increases the amplitude ( done)
3. replace the  sawtooth with double amplitude in to the data. ( I don't know how to do? sum? convolution?...?

Thank you

Comment: What about `data = saw_new`? `filter(b, a, saw_new)` will be almost identical to `saw_new` except for some boundary conditions at the concatenation point and the boundary frequencies which are somewhat more filtered out.

Comment: Do you want to generate data so that when you use a filter, you get `saw_new`? I thought that's what you meant, sorry (that's discussed [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31697/undoing-a-filter-operation-in-matlab)). 

What do you mean by "insert"/"replace" the sawtooth data?

Comment: @ Joh : No ;) I have a complex signal: lets say it is composed of x(t)=Alha*A+Beta*B+teta*C+sigma*T if I use band pass filter between [0.1 to 5] I will see only a sawthooth (A) wave then I change the amplitude of the sawtooth to twice bigger (2A). Now, I want to remove this sawtooth (A) from signal replace (2A). In such a way that if somebody use bandpath filter on superimposed signal they just see 2A.  Did I explain well ;) ?

Comment: Did you try just using addition: `new_data = orig_data - filtered_saw_data + saw_new;` Then using a filter will get close to the sawtooth you made, but not exact, as I mentioned. Is that on the right track at least?

Comment: Yes, I did but the result was not good after I decompose the sum